# Implementation of Linux cp in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, file, reinventing-the-wheel, linux

This is my simple implementation of the Unix `cp` command.  It is a C++ program but makes use of some of the lower level C library I/O functions.

Any suggestions for style or performance improvements would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    // cmd : cp file1 file2

    if ( argv[1] == nullptr || argv[2] == nullptr ){
        std::cout << "missing arguments: moderncp file1 file2 ";
        return 0;
    }
    const std::string input{argv[1]};
    const std::string output{argv[2]};

    // create a vector with 1024 byte allocated 
    std::vector<char> buf(1024);
    // input file descriptor 
    int infd = open(input.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
    // output file descriptor
    int outfd = open(output.c_str(),O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0664);

    while(true){
        auto count = read(infd,buf.data(),buf.size());
        if (count == 0) break;

        auto num_written = 0;
        auto num_to_write = count;
        while(num_written < num_to_write){
            num_written += write(outfd,buf.data()+num_written,count-num_written);

        }
    }
    close(infd);
    close(outfd);

    std::cout << input << '\t' << output ;
}
```

Comment: `moderncp file1 file2` could become `moderncp from to`

Comment: If you get an error in `write()` that will turn into an infinite loop. You need to make sure you correctly check error codes on all C functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Fix the bug

The program loops infinitely (actually, as @CrisLuengo correctly points out in a comment, it's not actually infinite.  However, it loops \$2^{54}\$ times for each 1024 bytes in the input file on a 64-bit machine, so it will certainly *feel* infinite for any human being waiting for the copy to complete!) if the output file already exists or can't be created.  That's a bug that should be fixed.  Generally, when a call can fail (as with `open`) it is important to test the result for failure before acting on the result.

### Use `std::fstream` for portability

This could be a completely portable program using only standard C++ libraries.  To do that, you'd omit `<fcntl.h>` and `<unistd.h>` and just use `fstream`.  I'm guessing you may have chosen to use the low-level functions for speed, but it's important to measure rather than assume.  The results may surprise you!

### Delete file before writing for speed

On several Linux platforms, overwriting an existing program is slower than creating one.  For that reason, one way to make sure that the program is as fast as possible is to call `std::remove` before doing the copy.

### Return valid error codes

A value of `0` as an error indicates no error on Linux and many other platforms.  If you execute `cp` with no arguments, it returns with a value of `1`.  If your program is intended to be an exact replacement, I'd recommend returning `1` instead of `0` if there are missing arguments.

### Check for arguments using `argc`

We can determine if there are the correct number of arguments by examining `argc`.  The way you're doing it has a problem:

```
if ( argv[1] == nullptr || argv[2] == nullptr ){
```

The problem is that if there are zero arguments, `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` might not be pointing to anything, so dereferencing them is *undefined behavior* and therefore not good programming practice.  In particular, you should be aware that [`argc` might be zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817316/can-argc-be-zero-on-a-posix-system) which would make testing `argv[1]` *undefined behavior*.

### Don't use `std::string` if what you need is a `char *`

In this case, both of the command line arguments are turned into `std::string`s but then used exclusively with `c_str()` to turn them back int `char *`.  Better would be to simply use `char *` without conversions to and from `std::string`.

### Prefer `std::array` to `std::vector`

If the bounds of your `std::vector` are known at compile-time (as in this case), then it's generally better to use `std::array` rather than `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` has provisions for resizing that this program doesn't use and doesn't need.  In fact, for this program, there's actually not much difference between a plain C-style array and a `std::array`.

### Name your constant

The buffer size is 1024 bytes, which is probably a bit on the small size.  I think it would be a slight improvement to increase the size and also to name that constant.

### Think about non-file files

Under Linux, we have not just files but also devices and named pipes.  Think about whether your program does what you intend if the input is a named pipe.  What happens if we try to copy to `/dev/null` ?

### An alternative version

Using most of those suggestions, here's an alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cout << "Usage: moderncp srcfile destfile\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::ifstream in{argv[1]};
    std::remove(argv[2]);
    std::ofstream out{argv[2]};
    if (!out) {
        std::cerr << "Could not create output file " << argv[2] << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    static constexpr std::size_t buffsize{1024};
    char buffer[buffsize];
    while (in.read(buffer, buffsize)) {
        out.write(buffer, buffsize);
    }
    out.write(buffer, in.gcount());
}
```

Note that because we're using `fstream`s for input and output, we don't have to explicitly close the files because the destructor will do so automatically as well as flushing the output buffer.

### Results

On my 64-bit Linux machine, copying a 5.3GiB file took 1:29 with the original program, 1:25 with this rewritten version and 1:21 with `cp`.  Changing the rewritten version to use an 8K buffer allowed it to complete in 0:59, so that's clearly an improvement.

Comment: A good answer, except for two issues: (1) The loop doesn’t loop infinitely if the output cannot be created, as `write` returns -1 in this case, not 0 (see my answer). (2) The way OP checks input is unconventional but correct, `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be a `nullptr`.

Comment: The loop will make 2 ^ 54 (about 1.8e16) calls to `write` for every 1k block of the input on a 64-bit machine.  That's at least going to *seem* infinite for a human being.  And for the second issue, while `argv[argc]` is as you say, there is no such guarantee for `argv[argc+1]` or beyond.

Comment: Yes, it's a very long loop... :)  `argv[1]` is always present, because `argc` is at least 1, and `argv[2]` is only accessed when `argv[1]` is not `nullptr`, in which case it exists also. Remember that `||` uses short-circuit.

Comment: It's admittedly obscure, but [`argc` can be zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817316/can-argc-be-zero-on-a-posix-system) so the code is faulty as written.

Comment: That is obscure... I've learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: I learn new things just about every time I visit here.  It's one of the reasons I keep coming back! :)

Comment: Ohh I want to be pedantic this morning. `if there are not two arguments` what follows not quite true. But probably good enough. Remember the `argv[]` array is always terminated with a null pointer. So `argv[argc] == nullptr` by definition. Does not change the advice of your excellent answer though. :-)

Comment: @MartinYork: I hereby award you the pedantry award for today. ;)  I've updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear why that code is a problem.

Answer (score 8):

## The command

```
// cmd : cp file1 file2
```

You then say:

```
    std::cout << "missing arguments: moderncp file1 file2 ";
```

Is it `cp file1 file2` or `moderncp file1 file2`?

In addition, I would provide more extensive documentation. What does `cp` do? The comment: `// cmd : cp file1 file2` should be comprehensive enough for me to understand what `cp` is and I should *not* have to use Google to figure it out. Using something like [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) to provide more incentive to document may be helpful.

## Handling Failure

```
    return 0;
```

The program failed. I have used `EXIT_FAILURE` in the past (in C), however, this would require `cstdlib` which I am not sure is a good idea. Nonetheless, `0` is reserved for a successful run, even `return 1;` would be better. (Maybe someone can comment on this?)

## Comments

```
// create a vector with 1024 byte allocated
```

Ok, I understand you created a 1024 byte vector, but you have not told me *why*. It's named `buf` so I know it is a buffer, but for what?

## Style

C++ does not have an equivalent to PEP 8, so technically as long as your style is consistent it is "correct". However, I usually see a blank line (or two) between the includes and functions, so:

```
#include<unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
```

becomes:

```
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
```

I have also seen spaces between arguments more often than not, so:

```
int infd = open(input.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
```

becomes:

```
int infd = open(input.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: Yes, you can define return codes however you want, as long as zero means success and non-zero means failure. You can specify in your documentation what each return code indicates.

Answer (score 8):

I am going to focus on these two lines of code:

```
int infd = open(input.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
int outfd = open(output.c_str(),O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0664);
```

Since you are making a point of using modern C++ to reimplement `cp`, I would expect you to use the modern C++ way of writing files. Instead, you use POSIX functions that don't even have a namespace...

If you don't want to use the streams, at least consider using `std::fopen`. The only thing that you cannot do using functions from the Standard Library is to set file permissions, but you don't want to do this anyway. The user will have set the `umask` according to personal preferences, you don't need to deviate from that.

What happens if `input` doesn't exist? What happens in `output` cannot be created? To the user, the result is identical to a successful file copy. There is no way to know if the `cp` call succeeded. You should check the values of `infd` and `outfd`, which will be -1 in case of failure, and return an error code. You can even check `errno` and give the user some more information about why the file couldn't be opened or created.

Actually, if `output` cannot be created, you end up in a very long loop that ends with UB:

```
 auto num_written = 0; // This is an `int`.
 while(num_written < num_to_write){
     num_written += write(outfd,buf.data()+num_written,count-num_written);
 }
```

`write` returns -1 on failure (`outfd` being not valid is cause for failure of course), so `num_written` will be decremented by 1 until it overflows. [Overflow is UB for signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c). Hopefully your implementation will lead to `num_written` to be very large at this point, breaking the loop.